# convert jsonix JSON schema to ElasticSearch type mapping using JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, elasticsearch, jsonschema

I have a jsonix JSON schema, here: [Example X3D JSON Schema](http://coderextreme.net/x3djson.jsonschema)

I'd like to convert the JSON schema to an ElasticSearth type mapping so I can upload my JSON documents into ElasticSearch without type conflicts.  I'm not sure what the next step is, and I may go with Mongoose if I can't find a solution (one next step is to hand craft the schema).